# Does ballerina support shift operators?

Tags: ballerina

What are the bit-wise operation ballerina support? And it seems shift operators are not support. It is help to write some complex logic easily.

Answer (score 1):

Ballerina does not any have any bit-wise operators at the moment. Please create a proposal in the form of a GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang).

Answer (score 0):

This implemented now for byte and int types. AND, OR, XOR bitwise operators and LEFT and RIGHT shift operators are supported.

https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/8963